# how can i smooth the graph values or extract main signals only

Tags: python, math, graph, smoothing, data-preprocessing

when i try to run the code below i get this graph

[image]

my code:

```
from numpy import nan
import json
import os
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statistics import mean, stdev


def smooth(t):
    new_t = []
    for i, x in enumerate(t):
        neighbourhood = t[max(i-2,0): i+3]
        m = mean(neighbourhood)
        s = stdev(neighbourhood, xbar=m)
        if abs(x - m) > s:
            x = ( t[i - 1 + (i==0)*2] + t[i + 1 - (i+1==len(t))*2] ) / 2
        new_t.append(x)
    return new_t
def outLiersFN(*U):
    outliers=[] # after preprocessing list
    #preprocessing Fc =| 2*LF1 prev by 1 - LF2 prev by 2 |
    c0 = -2     #(previous) by 2 #from original
    c1 =-1      #(previous)      #from original
    c2 =0       #(current)       #from original
    c3 = 1      #(next)          #from original
    preP = U[0] # original list
    if c2 == 0:
        outliers.append(preP[0])
        c1+=1
        c2+=1
        c0+=1
        c3+=1
    oldlen = len(preP)
    M_RangeOfMotion = 90
    while oldlen > c2 :
        if c3 == oldlen:
            outliers.insert(c2, preP[c2]) #preP[c2] >> last element in old list
            break
        if (preP[c2] > M_RangeOfMotion and preP[c2] < (preP[c1] + preP[c3])/2) or (preP[c2] < M_RangeOfMotion and preP[c2] > (preP[c1] + preP[c3])/2): #Check Paper 3.3.1
            Equ = (preP[c1] + preP[c3])/2 #fn of preprocessing # From third index # ==== inserting current frame
            formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(Equ) #with .2 number only
            equu = float(formatted_float)          #from string float to float
            outliers.insert(c2,equu)      # insert the preprocessed value to the List
            c1+=1
            c2+=1
            c0+=1
            c3+=1
        else :
            Equ = preP[c2] # fn of preprocessing #put same element (do nothing)
            formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(Equ)  # with .2 number only
            equu = float(formatted_float)  # from string float to float
            outliers.insert(c2, equu)  # insert the preprocessed value to the List
            c1 += 1
            c2 += 1
            c0 += 1
            c3 += 1
    return outliers
def remove_nan(list):
    newlist = [x for x in list if math.isnan(x) == False]
    return newlist

the_angel = [176.04, 173.82, 170.09, 165.3, 171.8, 178.3, 178.77, 179.24, 179.93, 180.0, 173.39, 166.78, 166.03, 165.28, 165.72, 166.17, 166.71, 167.26, 168.04, 167.22, 166.68, 166.13, 161.53, 165.81, 170.1, 170.05, 170.5, 173.01, 176.02, 174.53, 160.09, 146.33, 146.38, 146.71, 150.33, 153.95, 154.32, 154.69, 134.52, 114.34, 115.6, 116.86, 134.99, 153.12, 152.28, 151.43, 151.36, 152.32, 158.9, 166.52, 177.74, 178.61, 179.47, 167.44, 155.4, 161.54, 167.68, 163.96, 160.24, 137.45, 114.66, 117.78, 120.89, 139.95, 139.62, 125.51, 111.79, 112.07, 112.74, 110.22, 107.7, 107.3, 106.52, 105.73, 103.07, 101.35, 102.5, 104.59, 104.6, 104.49, 104.38, 102.81, 101.25, 100.62, 100.25, 100.15, 100.32, 99.84, 99.36, 100.04, 100.31, 99.14, 98.3, 97.92, 97.41, 96.9, 96.39, 95.88, 95.9, 95.9, 96.02, 96.14, 96.39, 95.2, 94.56, 94.02, 93.88, 93.8, 93.77, 93.88, 94.04, 93.77, 93.65, 93.53, 94.2, 94.88, 92.59, 90.29, 27.01, 32.9, 38.78, 50.19, 61.59, 61.95, 62.31, 97.46, 97.38, 97.04, 96.46, 96.02, 96.1, 96.33, 95.61, 89.47, 89.34, 89.22, 89.48, 89.75, 90.02, 90.28, 88.16, 88.22, 88.29, 88.17, 88.17, 94.98, 94.84, 94.69, 94.94, 94.74, 94.54, 94.69, 94.71, 94.64, 94.58, 94.19, 94.52, 94.85, 87.7, 87.54, 87.38, 95.71, 96.57, 97.11, 97.05, 96.56, 96.07, 95.76, 95.56, 95.35, 95.28, 95.74, 96.2, 96.32, 96.33, 96.2, 96.14, 96.07, 96.07, 96.12, 96.17, 96.28, 96.31, 96.33, 96.16, 96.05, 95.94, 95.33, 88.96, 95.0, 95.78, 88.19, 88.19, 88.19, 87.92, 87.93, 88.03, 87.94, 87.86, 87.85, 87.89, 88.08, 88.01, 87.88, 88.02, 88.15, 88.15, 88.66, 88.73, 88.81, 88.41, 88.55, 88.68, 88.69, 88.02, 87.35, 95.19, 95.39, 95.38, 95.37, 95.27, 95.17, 95.33, 95.32, 95.31, 95.37, 95.42, 95.34, 95.44, 95.53, 95.47, 95.41, 95.13, 94.15, 94.78, 97.64, 97.1, 96.87, 97.03, 96.76, 35.44, 23.63, 23.27, 24.71, 26.16, 96.36, 113.13, 129.9, 96.82, 63.74, 34.25, 33.42, 32.6, 30.69, 31.06, 31.43, 97.14, 97.51, 97.23, 98.54, 100.13, 100.95, 28.82, 33.81, 66.81, 99.82, 102.63, 101.9, 101.44, 102.19, 103.22, 103.67, 104.13, 104.07, 104.73, 105.46, 103.74, 102.02, 103.32, 102.59, 29.54, 28.08, 28.76, 29.79, 30.82, 113.51, 129.34, 145.16, 143.18, 148.29, 153.67, 166.14, 161.16, 151.64, 149.27, 146.9, 151.67, 153.02, 149.28, 145.53, 149.1, 152.67, 158.78, 164.89, 164.84, 164.8, 162.11, 159.42, 156.73, 156.28, 155.83, 156.4, 161.0, 165.59, 164.44, 159.73, 155.76, 156.97, 158.92, 159.15, 159.39, 159.99, 160.44, 160.88, 163.89, 166.9, 167.71, 167.11, 167.0, 167.44, 168.38, 153.16, 137.94, 137.65, 152.09, 169.49, 171.36, 173.22, 174.01, 174.0, 174.2, 174.41, 157.74, 141.09, 149.32, 157.57, 156.4, 148.4, 140.78, 141.06, 141.73, 143.05, 143.91, 156.59, 169.29, 172.17, 175.05, 175.29, 175.27, 175.15, 175.02, 174.81, 174.59, 174.76, 174.94, 175.18, 175.41, 175.23, 174.51, 174.64, 174.77, 174.56, 173.25, 172.38, 174.17, 176.4, 177.27, 177.29, 177.33, 178.64, 179.98, 179.99, 176.0, 172.88, 173.77, 173.8, 173.97, 174.72, 175.24, 176.89, 179.07, 179.27, 178.78, 178.29, 175.61, 174.21, 172.8, 173.05, 173.41, 173.77, 174.65, 175.52, 175.58, 176.15, 176.71, 159.12, 141.54, 141.12, 155.62, 170.53, 165.54, 160.71, 158.22, 156.35, 156.82, 158.55, 160.27, 161.33, 162.39, 162.37, 159.48, 156.59, 156.77, 158.05, 159.32, 158.49, 157.66, 157.7, 157.74, 158.44, 159.14, 150.13, 143.06, 136.0, 125.7, 115.41, 111.19, 106.97, 107.1, 107.24, 107.45, 107.67, 113.34, 119.01, 144.87, 170.73, 174.31, 177.89, 174.78, 171.67, 163.26, 134.58, 105.9, 102.98, 100.77, 101.05, 101.39, 101.73, 99.79, 98.71, 97.64, 97.8, 97.89, 96.67, 95.45, 94.33, 93.38, 92.44, 48.53, 91.4, 91.35, 91.34, 91.33, 90.92, 90.51, 88.63, 87.0, 86.74, 86.48, 96.79, 96.09, 95.46, 95.39, 94.32, 93.25, 93.31, 93.37, 93.11, 92.57, 93.41, 94.25, 96.48, 92.71, 88.94, 90.07, 90.43, 78.06, 77.69, 77.32, 90.1, 89.15, 89.14, 88.85, 88.38, 87.63, 121.2, 120.66, 86.89, 86.42, 85.69, 84.86, 84.86, 85.34, 85.82, 86.07, 86.32, 85.82, 85.32, 86.23, 86.69, 87.15, 87.04, 86.87, 86.58, 86.0, 85.41, 85.41, 85.53, 85.66, 85.7, 85.72, 85.75, 85.92, 86.09, 85.77, 85.45, 84.94, 85.55, 86.16, 86.21, 86.1, 85.77, 85.27, 84.56, 84.99, 85.38, 85.42, 85.98, 86.54, 86.5, 86.45, 86.56, 86.63, 86.35, 86.08, 85.82, 85.51, 85.21, 84.6, 84.84, 84.97, 85.1, 86.12, 86.88, 86.8, 86.46, 86.47, 87.23, 87.8, 88.0, 88.08, 88.16, 87.72, 87.63, 87.37, 86.42, 86.48, 87.24, 87.97, 88.09, 88.19, 88.32, 88.44, 87.82, 87.2, 86.03, 85.78, 91.5, 93.0, 88.2, 88.52, 88.42, 87.28, 85.73, 85.62, 85.5, 85.5, 87.06, 87.6, 88.1, 88.31, 88.53, 88.77, 89.14, 89.52, 89.46, 89.4, 90.28, 89.74, 91.28, 92.17, 92.16, 92.15, 93.08, 94.0, 94.66, 95.32, 94.13, 93.7, 93.32, 93.69, 94.58, 95.47, 97.25, 99.03, 99.63, 99.67, 99.71, 100.33, 101.58, 103.36, 103.49, 103.41, 106.31, 109.34, 109.28, 109.21, 107.76, 106.31, 105.43, 104.94, 104.44, 111.19, 117.93, 115.59, 113.24, 116.15, 119.06, 125.43, 140.72, 156.0, 161.7, 143.52, 135.33, 127.13, 127.68, 148.68, 169.68, 172.2, 174.72, 174.75, 174.66, 158.57, 142.63, 145.13, 153.29, 161.45, 163.34, 165.24, 162.25, 159.89, 159.07, 156.39, 155.21, 156.04, 159.29, 160.07, 160.85, 163.45, 162.93, 161.71, 160.06, 158.4, 144.74, 132.64, 134.57, 150.22, 165.86, 172.95, 174.12, 175.3, 175.5, 176.31, 177.71, 179.72, 168.13, 156.55, 146.24, 155.75, 176.0, 175.99, 175.98, 176.0, 176.02, 176.25, 175.13, 174.26, 173.38, 173.37, 173.46, 176.34, 174.55, 172.77, 168.45, 166.35, 166.47, 168.81, 167.43, 166.79, 167.35, 168.65, 168.51, 168.37, 168.88, 169.74, 171.19, 171.33, 169.91, 168.49, 167.11, 166.83, 167.01, 168.68, 170.34, 170.43, 172.15, 173.86, 177.62, 177.61, 175.34, 173.06, 176.47, 179.87, 179.9, 177.67, 175.67, 175.39, 175.36, 177.03, 176.0, 174.98, 174.96, 174.94, 175.76, 176.57, 169.05, 162.99, 164.97, 168.74, 172.51, 167.38, 165.08, 163.03, 163.81, 164.83, 164.81, 164.8, 165.88, 165.36, 159.61, 153.86, 153.57, 153.61, 153.65, 154.62, 155.58, 157.97, 156.35, 155.66, 154.98, 156.11, 157.24, 159.25, 159.6, 160.43, 161.26, 164.71, 168.17, 147.46, 126.92, 106.38, 105.23, 104.4, 105.37, 106.65, 109.21, 107.44, 104.65, 101.86, 102.35, 102.84, 102.79, 102.19, 101.59, 100.98, 100.38, 98.72, 97.73, 97.32, 96.9, 95.11, 93.97, 94.12, 94.12, 93.1, 92.08, 89.29, 90.35, 90.35, 90.35, 90.35, 86.95, 86.37, 86.06, 85.74, 94.56, 93.16, 92.46, 91.76, 88.55, 85.33, 87.52, 92.18, 93.68, 95.18, 94.4, 92.17, 89.94, 89.4, 89.37, 99.44, 100.98, 102.52, 103.18, 88.96, 88.23, 87.5, 85.2, 85.19, 86.87, 121.42, 155.96, 155.97, 155.97, 86.2, 86.5, 86.8, 87.22, 87.36, 87.34, 87.03, 87.04, 87.05, 86.36, 85.68, 85.71, 85.84, 85.93, 86.01, 86.04, 86.08, 85.92, 86.05, 86.18, 86.17, 86.19, 86.23, 86.22, 86.09, 85.92, 85.66, 85.69, 85.69, 85.31, 84.91, 84.93, 84.95, 84.93, 84.91, 84.9, 84.9, 84.9, 84.9, 85.38, 85.52, 85.66, 85.66, 85.4, 85.14, 85.47, 85.8, 85.72, 85.64, 86.09, 85.84, 85.27, 85.47, 85.66, 85.59, 85.52, 85.38, 85.39, 85.28, 85.17, 85.39, 85.7, 85.98, 86.26, 86.61, 92.97, 93.15, 86.58, 86.58, 86.53, 86.47, 98.55, 99.41, 100.16, 100.9, 89.19, 90.28, 91.38, 91.39, 91.4, 91.44, 92.05, 131.05, 170.63, 170.13, 162.43, 125.64, 88.85, 88.85, 99.08, 100.38, 101.69, 100.74, 99.79, 96.33, 93.31, 93.73, 94.87, 96.01, 96.93, 97.85, 98.97, 97.85, 98.14, 99.37, 102.01, 103.8, 105.58, 108.52, 108.12, 107.72, 106.75, 106.82, 109.08, 112.37, 112.52, 112.66, 112.97, 114.12, 115.64, 117.1, 118.57, 126.13, 133.69, 149.27, 163.96, 166.62, 169.27, 164.94, 160.61, 149.35, 141.18, 143.41, 143.57, 149.26, 157.49, 159.94, 151.93, 147.47, 145.97, 145.56, 145.15, 143.85, 142.54, 142.18, 142.43, 143.12, 144.41, 144.38, 151.99, 159.59, 174.81, 174.94, 175.84, 176.87, 162.41, 152.94, 151.59, 155.24, 155.22, 155.19, 155.04]

p0 = outLiersFN(smooth(remove_nan(the_angel)))

the_angel = p0
plt.plot(the_angel) #list(filter(fun, L1))
plt.show()
print((the_angel))
```

how can i smooth the values in (the_angel) to get graph like this (red line)

i mean ignoring all unnecessary and noisy values and get only main line instead

[image]

you can edit my code or suggest me new filter or algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas has a [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) method for dataframes that you can use to calculate the mean over a window of values, e.g. the 70 closest ones:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

WINDOW_SIZE = 70

the_angel = [176.04, 173.82, 170.09, 165.3, 171.8,  # ... 
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'the angel': the_angel})

df[f'mean of {WINDOW_SIZE}'] = df['the angel'].rolling(
    window=WINDOW_SIZE, center=True).mean()
df.plot(color=['blue', 'red']);
```

[image: rolling mean]